# On Click Expand JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created onclick expand menu when clicked shows a list of items. But the problem is when i click on the items it collapses. I just want it to collapse when i click on the main menu but not on the items inside it!!!

This is the code for onclick slide menu js

```
$("#population_expanderHead").click(function(){
        $("#population_expanderContent").slideToggle();

    });
```

and this is the code in html

```
<li id="population_expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">
    Population
    <div id="population_expanderContent" style="display:none">
    <ul>
    <li>Population Distribution<br /></li>
    <li>Proportional Population Distribution<br /></li>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Your HTML makes no sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. Here's a simply way:

```
$("#population_expanderHead").click(function(event){
   if( event.target == this ){
      $("#population_expanderContent").slideToggle();
   }
});
```